# Using Private Browsing keyboard shortcut with Firefox and Vimperator

Tags: macos, firefox, vimperator

I am using Firefox 15.0 on OS X Mountain Lion alongside with vimperator. Note that I am using a Windows keyboard.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> is for moving focus to left tab in vimperator. However, the latest Firefox has also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to enable private browsing.

I looked for private browsing with FF "Customizable Shortcuts" addon but there is only <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> binding associated to it.

How can the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> private browsing binding be turned off?

Comment: Ctrl-P should be a shortcut for printing the current page. You sure it turns on private browsing?

Comment: meta + p is for print on mac.

Answer (score 9):

Private browsing mode on Firefox is initiated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

When using vimperator, the key <kbd>i</kbd> can be used to instruct vimperator to ignore the next key press  and to pass it directly along to the browser. Thus to achieve what you asked, press <kbd>i</kbd>  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Note, that <kbd>i</kbd> only ignores the key press that directly follows. If you want vimperator to ignore key presses for a longer period of time, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>. All key presses are then passed straight over to the browser until you press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> again.

Comment: that doesn't work for me. press `i` did prompt a `IGNORE` text on vimperator bar. but pressing `meta` `shift` `p` still prompt private browsing. note that on Mac, `ctrl` `p` also prompt private browsing.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 13.04 with FF 22 and Vimperator. (I know, this is not Mac)

Comment: Also there is an add-in for Firefox called **Private tab** which makes it available to open a single private tab (without opening a whole private window) using the `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `t` keyboard combination.

Answer (score 1):

```
nnoremap <c-s-p> i<c-s-p>
```

on `~/.vimperatorrc` and `:source ~/.vimperatorrc` automates what [Dave said](https://superuser.com/a/477196/128124) and gives us Ctrl+Shift+P back.